# Textblock selected foreground color in datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, datagrid

I have created a datagrid in WPF...
I have defined several custom Columns..

```
 <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeadC}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeadCPercent}"  Foreground="#FFF05D1D" />
           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
 </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

The problem is that when a row is slected the seconds textblock color doesnt change and it is hardly visible...

Any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `DataTrigger` to the `DataTemplate` triggers collection that would change foreground based on selected state of the row. Like in the following example:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeadC}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbPercent" Text="{Binding HeadCPercent}" Foreground="#FFF05D1D"/>
  </StackPanel>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dg:DataGridRow}}}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="tbPercent" Value="Blue" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemlate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

I took this [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/8849add2-3ce0-4f0c-bfca-92defe0d8362) as a basis and adjusted it to your question. I could made a typo in the code but you should get the idea :). Hope it helps.

Comment: To use the default system color for highlighted text use `Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrush}"` instead of `Blue` above.